# Index Route missing in Resource Routes Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am unable to get the index route of my resource when using some prefix,

when my route is this:

```
Route::resource('subjects', 'SubjectController')->middleware('auth:admin');
```

i got this route listing:

```
| subjects                | subjects.index
| subjects                | subjects.store
| subjects/create         | subjects.create
| subjects/{subject}      | subjects.update
| subjects/{subject}      | subjects.destroy
| subjects/{subject}      | subjects.show
| subjects/{subject}/edit | subjects.edit
```

But when i add a prefix like this:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('subjects', 'SubjectController')->middleware('auth:admin');
});
```

The index route disappears, and routes list become this:

```
| admin/subjects                | subjects.store
| admin/subjects/create         | subjects.create
| admin/subjects/{subject}      | subjects.update
| admin/subjects/{subject}      | subjects.destroy
| admin/subjects/{subject}      | subjects.show
| admin/subjects/{subject}/edit | subjects.edit
```

Comment: and also those routes aren't prefixed, they should be `admin/subjects/....` so something else is going on

Comment: that was a typing mistake , now corrected the question

Comment: Any solutions now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got the solution. actually there was another route ('subjects') in my web.php. I needed to remove this, since they both were colliding.